# Making images responsive in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, size

http://www.dirkdunn.com/web2

I recently made a responsive layout, setting the..

```
max-width:100%;
```

property in google chrome, which works perfectly for adjusting the header image size, however, in other broweser's such as firefox, the image overlaps the parent container on the left size.

I am familiar with scott jehls picture.js polyfill, however specifying the image size for each screen size sounds like a headache inside the picture tags, is there any way to combat this in other browsers similarly to how google chrome resizes this naturally?

or at the very least, is there some kind of math formula for knowing the right picture size via the browser width? thanks.

Comment: http://www.dirkdunn.com/web2

Comment: Why have you floated '#headlogo' to the right ? When disabled it appears fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `max-height` of `img` to `100%`, however you don't have the `width` of it's parent defined. So, it becomes confusing to the browser to determine 100% of what thing.

Let's give the parent a `width` -

```
#headlogo {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also set the margin accordingly, you might wanna use `margin: 0` for `#headlogo`.

Comment: thank you very much, that worked.just took away the width property of header also. was it my margin that was pushing it out?

Comment: @DirkDunn `margin` was pushing out a bit, but the real issue is, there's no `width` defined for it's parent (`#headlogo`).

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the h1-parent of the image and it works. (FF 32)

Comment: thanks, that covers the resize, but it still moves out of container?

Comment: No, it stays in the `#container`...
But it's the same solution like @aniskhan001 mentioned, because if you remove the h1, the parent of the image will have a set width. But however, I don't prefer an image-tag inside of a heading...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
max-width: 100%; 
display:block; 
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to center the logo.

I would remove the float: right from the H1 and remove the margin you have. Than I would add a text-align: center to the H1. This will solve your responsive logo issue and keep the logo centered.

### Your Current CSS

```
#headlogo {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 15% 0 0;
}
```

### Proposed Solution CSS

```
#headlogo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I saw the float property and removed it before I even read this, I had it there from a previous type of layout I was making.